# javascript and highcharts was not getting in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

this is the first time i am using ajax, please help me,
The problem is when i call the ajax function response is loading with list of table data but highcharts and javascript of excel export is not getting. in main.html i have added span in that i need the response of source.html when i click on **reports and graphs** button.

main.html:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<style>
.scrollit {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 350px;
    width: 600px;
}
</style>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".button").click(function() {

        $(".table2excel").table2excel({
            exclude : ".noExl",
            name : "Excel Document Name"
        });
    });
}); 
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var urls="source.html";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("report-response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",urls,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Reports and graphs" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">
<!--- this span response is from source.html  -->
    <span id="report-response"> </span>
<!---     -->
</body>

</html>
```

source.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
   <script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>  
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<script language = "JavaScript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".button").click(function() {

            $(".table2excel").table2excel({
                exclude : ".noExl",
                name : "Excel Document Name"
            });
        });
    }); 
         $(document).ready(function() {  
            var chart = {
               type: 'column'
            };
            var title = {
               text: 'Daily Water Consumed'   
            };
            var subtitle = {
               text: 'Source: highcharts'  
            };
            var xAxis = {
               categories: ["18-10-2017","19-10-2017","20-10-2017","21-10-2017","22-10-2017","23-10-2017"],
               crosshair: true
            };
            var yAxis = {
               min: 0,
               title: {
                  text: 'Water Consumed (litres)'         
               }      
            };
            var tooltip = {
               headerFormat: '<span style = "font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
               pointFormat: '<tr><td style = "color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                  '<td style = "padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} litres</b></td></tr>',
               footerFormat: '</table>',
               shared: true,
               useHTML: true
            };
            var plotOptions = {
               column: {
                  pointPadding: 0.2,
                  borderWidth: 0
               }
            };  
            var credits = {
               enabled: false
            };
            var series= [
               {
                  name: 'Flow value',
                  data: [16,20,25,10,0,15],
                  color:'#0388e6' 

               }
            ];     
            var json = {};   
            json.chart = chart; 
            json.title = title;   
            json.subtitle = subtitle; 
            json.tooltip = tooltip;
            json.xAxis = xAxis;
            json.yAxis = yAxis;  
            json.series = series;
            json.plotOptions = plotOptions;  
            json.credits = credits;
            $('#container').highcharts(json);

         });
      </script> 
<style>
.scrollit {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 350px;
    width: 600px;
}
</style>
                <input type="button" value="export table to excel" class="button"/>
        <br>
        <hr>   
                <br>
<center>
<br>
<div style="display: flex; padding-left: 70px;">
        <div class="scrollit">
            <table class="table2excel">
                <tr>
                    <th>Site Id</th>
                    <th>Serial Number</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Flow value</th>
                    <th>Cumulative value</th>
                </tr>

                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>

            </table>
        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <div id="container" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
</center>

    <br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the file source.html where are stored main.html and change  `var urls="source.html";` to your code.

Comment: yes, i did that but i am getting only table data but not getting highcharts

Comment: No sure about what is the problem, "`getting only table data`" this is empty or no?

Comment: table data, i mean normal text data is getting, but highcharts is missing

Comment: Any data from `$('#container').highcharts(json); console.log(json);` here

Comment: sorry, i did not get your question, what data from $('#container').highcharts(json); console.log(json);

Comment: no change, even after adding console.log(json) after $('#container').highcharts(json);  if button isn't trrigger the action then normal textual data wouldnt come right

Comment: ok so if i understand you want to save as excel doc your own datas getting from the page? or you want to load a excel file datas to print inside the highcharts for showing datas ?

Comment: yes  exactly, but the data is dynamic, and taking only two parameters from table to show highcharts

Comment: to save or loading data? or only to save your datas taken from the highchart ? because isn't the same way on regard of your code.

Comment: i want to take two parameters from the data(table) and that should be shown on highcharts (x-axis and  y-axis),  the data couldn't be static it is dynamic

Comment: ok so i need 20 min. To answer something ... ;)

Comment: ya,  no problem, thanks for you help and patience

Comment: just try if is what you should expect. Regards.

Comment: Then what about highcharts, it's missing know

Comment: i think you did not understand my intension, my main aim is to show source.html in main.html when i click on **reports and graphs** button.

Comment: if you open my **source.html** you can find **table** and **highcharts**, the same thing should be displayed in **main.html** under the **reports and graphs** button only with out redirecting to **source.html** using ajax function, and one more thing **source.html** contains **dynamic** content not static just for example i have posted static html page. in **main.html** actually i have to pass three parameters in ajax function url, 1- reportType 2- fromDate and  3- toDate, example url should like **(source.jsp?reportType="dayWise"&fromDate="20-10-2017"&toDate="24-10-2017" ) **

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this : dataTables.js jquery.js and html5 buttons bootstrap ... for cross browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'excel',
      text: 'Export excel',
      className: 'exportExcel',
      filename: 'Export excel',
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
          page: 'all'
        }
      }
    }, 
    {
      extend: 'copy',
      text: '<u>C</u>opie presse papier',
      className: 'exportExcel',
      key: {
        key: 'c',
        altKey: true
      }
    }, 
    {
      text: 'Alert Js',
      className: 'exportExcel',
      action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
        alert('Activated!');
        // console.log(table);

        // new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
        //   buttons: [{
        //     text: 'gfdsgfsd',
        //     action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
        //       alert('ok!');
        //     }
        //   }]
        // });
      }
    }]
  });

});
```

```css
.exportExcel{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>



<body>
              <table id="example" class="table2excel display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Site Id</th>
                    <th>Serial Number</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Flow value</th>
                    <th>Cumulative value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
                    <tr> <td> asdasd </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas  </td><td> asdas </td><td> asdas </td></tr>
            </table>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/oGRYJV

Comment: if you open my source.html you can find table and highcharts, the same thing should be displayed in main.html under the reports and graphs button only with out redirecting to source.html using ajax function, and one more thing source.html contains dynamic content not static just for example i have posted static html page. in main.html actually i have to pass three parameters in ajax function url, 1- reportType 2- fromDate and 3- toDate, example url should like **(source.jsp?reportType="dayWise"&fromDate="20-10-2017"&toD‌​ate="24-10-2017" )**